# Validates greater than existing column in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I want to validate on update that `:budget_price` is always greater than previous value existing in this column.

I make a check on client side by html5 but how I validate it in model.rb

I write

```
validates :budget_price, :numericality => { :greater_than => :budget_price }, :on => :update
```

But it doesn't work properly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change your second `:budget_price` to `:budget_price_was` like

```
validates :budget_price, :numericality => { :greater_than => :budget_price_was }, :on => :update
```

About other methods, see also http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html